# Cannot connect to Hyper-V host Server 2016

Tags: windows-server-2016

I'm hoping someone can help me out with this, because it's driving me up the wall.

I have 3 new installations of Windows Server 2016, joined to a Domain, all 3 running Hyper-V, including the administration tools. Separately, they all work, but I can't connect to any of them remotely, with any user account.

I have tried a new user account, adding it to the Hyper-V administrators group, as well as the built-in administrators account.

My error message is:

> You do not have the required permission to complete this task. Contact the administrator of the authorization policy for the computer.

I'm convinced it's an authentication error of some kind, but I need some guidance on where to look or what else it could be.